# In play 2.1.2 I am trying to use Cache API - getting error while using public static void set(java.lang.String key,java.lang.Object value)

Tags: playframework-2.0

Im trying to use Cache in Play 2.1.2.
While all the javadocs currently portray the available methods for setting :

```
// Sets a value without expiration.
static void set(java.lang.String key, java.lang.Object value)

//Sets a value with expiration.
static void set(java.lang.String key, java.lang.Object value, int expiration)
```

These are not available while using eclipse.
Also while trying to compile from play command prompt i Am getting error :

```
sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: method set in class Cache cannot be applied to given types;]
```

The signature of the only method available to set values is :

```
void play.api.cache.Cache.set(String arg0, Object arg1, int arg2, Application arg3)
```

Any ideas on what needs to be passed as the 4th parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of not mixing Scala and Java API.

The following method is Scala:

```
void play.api.cache.Cache.set(String arg0, Object arg1, int arg2, Application arg3)
```

And the following is Java:

```
static void play.cache.Cache.set(java.lang.String key, java.lang.Object value)
```

In Playframework, the Scala API is contained in the `*.api.*` packages, and the Java API does not contain "api" in the package qualified name.

So, make sure you used `import play.cache.Cache` and not `import play.api.cache.Cache`